# js weird bracket syntax

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new to javascript but i usually understand most of the scripts that i use.
today i wanted to port somme of moment.js to haxe .
but i'm quite disapointed by this syntax:

```
var args = seconds < 45 && ['s', seconds] ||
            minutes === 1 && ['m'] ||
            minutes < 45 && ['mm', minutes] ||
            hours === 1 && ['h'] ||
            hours < 22 && ['hh', hours] ||
            days === 1 && ['d'] ||
            days <= 25 && ['dd', days] ||
            days <= 45 && ['M'] ||
            days < 345 && ['MM', round(days / 30)] ||
            years === 1 && ['y'] || ['yy', years];
```

you can find it at line number 529 of this file https://github.com/timrwood/moment/blob/master/moment.js#L532

what does the `["s", seconds]` mean ? 
is it an array, a json pattern ?

thx for the replies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically `args` will be an array with one or two elements that represents time interval. Depending on how long it is it will be measured in seconds, minutes, hours etc.

> what does the ["s", seconds] mean ? is it an array, a json pattern ?

It is an array definition.

Comment: thanks for the reply !
so how should look args after these switches ?
i don't understand what the && does in that situation.

Comment: It is very tricky, I know:-) If the condition to the left of && is true then args will be set to the expression to the right of &&. Here is a fiddle to experiment with: http://jsfiddle.net/Pharaon/qVA2Y/1/

Comment: Yes, you can treat it this way